# Question about working with PDFs and JSONs with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pdf, pdf-generation

So I wrote code in Python that automatically fills the fields of given PDF with data from given JSON, but there is one problem. The problem is that for the date or postcode, there is different field for each digit and since I fill the data from the JSON based on the field names, I should write each digit separately instead of just writing the postcode or data in one line.

This is screenshot of how the Postcode fields are in the PDF. Since there is different field for each digit, I should extract the field name from the PDF and then for each field name to search its value in the JSON, so the problem is that I should write each digit next to the field name, instead of just writing all digits of the postcode or data for example.

[Here is how the fields looks in the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYoqh.png)

I wrote this code in Python:

```
import PyPDF2
import json

pdf_file_path = "example.pdf"

json_file_path = "file.json"

with open(json_file_path, 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file_path)

if pdf.is_encrypted:
    print("PDF is encrypted")
else:
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    for page_num in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        page = pdf.pages[page_num]

        for field_name, field_value in data.items():
            pdf_writer.update_page_form_field_values(page, {field_name: field_value})

        pdf_writer.add_page(page)

    output_pdf_path = "C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\sample.pdf"
    with open(output_pdf_path, 'wb') as output_pdf_file:
        pdf_writer.write(output_pdf_file)

    print(f"PDF was succesfully filled at {output_pdf_path}")
```

And this is the JSON that I use for this PDF, I hope to make sense to you:

```
{
"Company number 2": "2",
"Company number 3": "5",
"Company number 4": "3",
"Company number 5": "4",
"Company number 6": "2",
"Company number 7": "4",
"Company number 8": "9",
"Company number 9": "8",
"Company name 2": "Example Company Name", 
"Company name 3": "Example Company Name 2", 
"Title 3": "Example Title", 
"Forename 3": "Example Forename",
"Surname 3": "Example Surname",
"Former names 3": "Example Former names", 
"Country / State of residence 3": "Example Country", 
"Nationality 3": "Example Nationality", 
"Business occupation 3": "Example Business occupation", 
"Service address builiding name/number 3": "Example building name", 
"Service address street 3": "Example address street", 
"Service address street 4": "Example address street", 
"Service address post town 3": "Example address post", 
"Service address county/region 3": "Example region", 
"Service address country 3": "Example address country", 
"Usual residential address building name/numner 3": "Usual residential address", 
"Usual residential address street 3": "Usual residential street 3", 
"Usual residential address street 4": "Usual residential street 4", 
"Usual residential address post town 3": "Usual post town", 
"Usual residential address county/region 3": "Usual region", 
"Usual residential address country  3": "Usual residential country", 
"Check Box 5": "/Yes",
"Consent to act 3": "/Yes",
"Additional former names 3": "Example former name 3", 
"Additional former names 4": "Example former name 4", 
"Additional former names 5": "Example former name 5", 
"Additional former names 6": "Example former name 6", 
"Additional former names 7": "Example former name 7", 
"Additional former names 8": "Example former name 8", 
"Additional former names 9": "Example former name 9", 
"Additional former names 10": "Example former name 10", 
"Sig 6": "Usual Sig", 
"Presenter information contact name 01": "Example contact name", 
"Presenter information company name 2": "Example company name 2", 
"Presenter information company name 3": "Example company name 3", 
"Presenter information address 2": "Example information address 2", 
"Presenter information address 3": "Example information address 3", 
"Presenter information address 4": "Example information address 4", 
"Presenter information post town 2": "Example information town 2", 
"Presenter information county/region 2": "Example information region 2", 
"Presenter information country 2": "Example information country 2", 
"Presenter information DX  2": "Example information DX 2", 
"Presenter information telephone 2": "Example information telephone 2"
}
```